# best way to load external content

Tags: jquery, html, load

I'm currently working on a one page size. everything is going well and the load speed is still fast enough. still I wanna prevent my website from loading slow. So I was thinking about the following

I have a portfolio page with tiles on it. when you click on a tile a black opacity overlay and a slider will pop up.

Currently I'm using this method:

```
<div class="item" id="2"><img src="picture of project"/>
  <div class="hoverOverlay" onclick="$('#port2').show(); $('#portfolioOverlaybg').fadeIn();">
  </div>
</div>
```

This means I will load all portfolio slider divs when the page opens. When people click on a portfolio item (in this example item 2 it will simply show this. and hide it no closing.

Now I found this method And I wonder if this is a more efficient way:

```
$(function() {
  $('#hoverOverlay2').click(function() { 
        $('#port2').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false; // And prevent it following the link
  });
});
```

So in this case I will link to a file on my server to load.

And if someone thinks both methods are not very good. what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically - it's sort of a preference here.  Will the loading of the additional HTML on the page all at once slow things down, or no?  Do you prefer to load everything at once? Then go the first route.

If you want a cleaner file, and don't mind the extra time to load at time of click, go the second route.

If you have hundreds of projects, the first route would be a bad idea.  If you have 6, maybe not.  It's really up to you which route you want to go, either would be suitable, but if your scale starts leaning to the large side of things, the second route would be more maintainable.